# Two different domain name extension pointing to same Wordpress copy?

Tags: wordpress, dns, cross-domain

We have a Wordpress site running on Mydomain.org and Mydomain.com is forwarding to domain.org currently through redirect in the virtual host configuration.

My question is can we terminate the redirect for Mydomain.com and do something to make it like when a visitor land on Mydomain.com, it actually showing the exact content of Mydomain.org, but actually still only maintain one copy of Wordpress on Mydomain.org at the backend,  so only maintain one WordPress copy instead of creating another copy of WordPress on Mydomain.com

Create domain alias will work?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll get penalized for duplicate content by the Search Engines doing this sort of thing.

Comment: Yes you can. I will assume Apache since you mentioned Wordpress. Apache supports multiple domain names. You can specify the same directory for each domain name. You can also specify that one domain name is an `Alias` for another domain name. Apache is very flexible in these areas.